# Spring - Parameter value did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba con Spring-Boot y Angular, en Spring tengo dos entidades (Project y ProjectCategory) y quiero buscar los productos por categoria (se tienen dos tablas obviamente).

```
http://localhost:8080/api/products/search/findByCategoryProduct?id=1
Error:
Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.todolist.demo.entity.ProductCategory (n/a)]
```

```
DaoRepository:
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>
{
    Page<Product> findByCategoryProduct(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
public class Product
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private long id_product;

    @Column(name = "sku_product")
    private String sku_product;

    @Column(name = "name_product")
    private String name_product;

    @Column(name = "description_product")
    private String description_product;

    @Column(name = "unit_price_product")
    private BigDecimal unit_price_product;

    @Column(name = "image_product")
    private String image_product;

    @Column(name = "active_product")
    private boolean active_product;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date date_created;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_product")
    //@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date last_updated_product;

    @Column(name = "units_in_stock_product")
    private int units_in_stock_product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_product", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory categoryProduct;
```

ProductCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ProductCategory
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_procat")
    private long id_procat;

    @Column(name = "name_procat")
    private String name_procat;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "categoryProduct")
    private Set<Product> products;
```

Answer (score 0):

Queria entender porque no encontraba ningun valor con la relacion en la otra tabla sin tener que implementar un @Query pero por falta de tiempo, esta fue la solucion rapida:

```
@Query("select p from Product p inner join ProductCategory  pc on pc.id_procat = p.categoryProduct.id_procat where pc.id_procat = :id")
    Page<Product> findByCategoryProduct(@RequestParam("id") long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo tu problema está en que estás llamando a la categoría, pero no le has dicho con qué atributo de los que tienes en esa clase debe buscar; si vas a buscar por el id, quedaría así:

```
Page<Product> findByCategoryProduct_Id_procat(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Puedes ayudarte de las sugerencias (autocompletado) para verificar la sintaxis de acuerdo al parámetro que quieres usar